# Linker Error: Cannot open input file 'd3dx9.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, directx, d3dx

This is a very simple question but I have been searching for a while now and have no luck. Im supposed to add it to the linker I beleive? Which is Project Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. Im just confused on exactly what to do. Thank you.

Comment: One easy solution is to use `#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9")` directly in the source code file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: Be aware that ``d3dx9.lib`` along with the entire DirectX SDK is deprecated. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [this blog post](https://aka.ms/dxsdk).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package to your project and not use the legacy DirectX SDK at all. This puts the headers `d3dx9*.h`, `d3dx10*.h`, and `d3dx11*.h` into your include path. It also adds `d3dx9.lib`, `d3dx10.lib`, and `d3dx11.lib` to your link settings, and provides the required runtime DLLs 'side-by-side'. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/).

Otherwise, to integrate the legacy DirectX SDK requires some special include/lib path ordering in VC++ Directories, and you'll have a number of other quirks to contend with. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-#using-directx-sdk-projects-with-visual-studio) for the details.

> Of course, the real question is "Why are you using legacy Direct3D 9 in the first place instead of Direct3D 11?". For Direct3D 11 or Direct3D 12, you should avoid the legacy DirectX SDK and D3DX9/D3DX10/D3DX11 entirely. See [Living without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).